# Render in a different order on the page breaks the routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, acts-as-votable

I have Challenges containing Puns, and it is possible to vote on puns. On the Challenge Show page, all puns are rendered and show their votes count. This is currently on the view page:

```
  <%= render @challenge.puns.reverse %>
  <br>
  <div id="form">
    <%= render "puns/form" %>
  </div>
```

I want the puns form to appear above the items (puns) already submitted. But if swap them around, like this:

```
  <div id="form">
    <%= render "puns/form" %>
  </div>
  <%= render @challenge.puns.reverse %>
```

I get a controller error and pun.id is not suddenly not available and the voting link breaks.

```
No route matches {:action=>"upvote", :challenge_id=>"9", :controller=>"puns", :id=>nil}, missing required keys: [:id]
```

Here is the puns/form part that is causing the issue

```
<% if signed_in? %>
  <% if current_user.voted_for? pun %>
    <%= pun.votes_for.size %>
    <span class="pun_text"><%= link_to pun.pun_text, challenge_pun_path(@challenge, pun.id) %></span>
  <% else %>
    <%= link_to like_challenge_pun_path(@challenge, pun.id), method: :put do %>
      <span class="heart_like">&#10084;</span>&nbsp;<%= pun.votes_for.size %>&nbsp;
    <% end %>
      <span class="pun_text"><%= link_to pun.pun_text, challenge_pun_path(@challenge, pun.id) %></span>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

It is the `like_challenge_pun_path` that throws an error but I cannot understand why. I am declaring `@challenge` again here, so it should be able to get the id.

Here is the form for the puns:

```
<%= form_for([@challenge, @challenge.puns.build]) do |f| %>
  <span class=".emoji-picker-container">
    <%= f.text_area :pun_text, placeholder: "Add pun", data: { emojiable: true } %>
  </span>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Also, here is my routes setup

```
  resources :challenges do
    resources :puns do
      member do
        put "like", to: "puns#upvote"
        put "dislike", to: "puns#downvote"
      end
    end
  end
```

and the corresponding action to upvote

```
def upvote
  @pun = @challenge.puns.find(params[:id])
  @pun.upvote_by current_user
  redirect_to @challenge
end
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Where is the `pun` from in the `puns/form` partial?

Comment: @fongfan999 I assume pun works because "@challenge" is already declared in the show view. And that is why it breaks when I switch them around?

Comment: Hi @matski, are you sure that the app will works when we didn't change the order? If it works, it's weird

Comment: @fongfan999 it definitely works. 
  `Rendered collection of puns/_pun.html.erb [9 times] (27.9ms)
  Rendered puns/_form.html.erb (9.8ms)
  Rendered challenges/show.html.erb within layouts/application (87.6ms)`

Comment: you are signing in?

Comment: @fongfan999 Please note there is also a form partial for puns `<%= form_for([@challenge, @challenge.puns.build]) do |f| %>
  <span class=".emoji-picker-container">
    <%= f.text_area :pun_text, placeholder: "Add pun", data: { emojiable: true } %>
  </span>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170012/discussion-between-matski-and-fongfan999).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the code is for the puns collection.
I assume the issue is that in the form you have something like:

```
@challenge.puns.build
```

So in `@challenge.puns` collection appears not persisted record (without id), so path for this model cannot be generated.

As a quick solution I suggest:

```
<%= render @challenge.puns.reverse.select(&:persisted?) %>
```

UPDATE:
As I assumed you have

```
<%= form_for([@challenge, @challenge.puns.build]) do |f| %>
```

You can also try:

```
<%= form_for([@challenge, Pun.new]) do |f| %>
```

Or solve it in the controller. But need to see controller code for it.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I posted the puns/form in my original post. Is this the one you mean? I will add the _pun.html.erb view if you would like to see it?

Comment: If it is form, where is did you assign `pun` variable?
And yes, would be great to see `_pun.html.erb`
Also, want to ask did the change I've suggested help?

Comment: I just added the puns form to my original post. Your quick solution works, yes. I can put the form above the rendered puns, create and vote on new puns.

But I would be very interested to know how to build this better. Because actually I cannot see where the pun variable is being set. In all other pages I set @pun in the Puns controller. (e.g. for deleting `@pun = @challenge.puns.find(params[:id])`) so I don't understand why it works differently here...?

Comment: As I assumed you have this code:
`<%= form_for([@challenge, @challenge.puns.build]) do |f| %>`
It adds new pun item to the collection `@challenge.puns`.

And you have loop by puns collection.
So when this code is after loop, then it iterates over persisted items only,  but when this code is before loop it adds new not persisted item and during iterations your code works with it.
The other solution for your issue is:
`<%= form_for([@challenge, Pun.new]) do |f| %>`

Comment: Thanks for your help!